# Applescript Droplet - opening a file in Photoshop CS6

Tags: applescript, photoshop

I'm creating a droplet with Applescript which will basically open the file in photoshop CS6 and then process it.

So far I can't get past the opening the file bit. Can someone identify whats wrong with this code:

```
on open {the_PDFs}

set myFilePath to the_PDFs

tell application "Adobe Photoshop CS6"
    open myFilePath as PDF with options {class:PDF open options, mode:RGB,    resolution:300, page:x, constrain proportions:false}
end tell

end open
```

I keep getting an error saying "Can't get Alias "Macintosh HD:Users:MyName:Desktop:myFile.pdf"

Answer (score 0):

ok so a few things

not sure why you are using brackets but you need to remove those

next the_PDFs is an array of files no a single file so you must loop through them

last you tell it to open page x but never define x

```
on open the_PDFs
    set x to 1
    repeat with afile in the_PDFs
        tell application "Adobe Photoshop CS5.1"
            open afile as PDF with options {class:PDF open options, mode:RGB, resolution:300, page:x, constrain proportions:false}
        end tell
    end repeat
end open
```

NOTE: I do not own CS6 so i could not test in CS6 though there shouldn't be any change in this

Answer (score -1):

Put away the brackets from the first line, it should work:

```
on open the_PDFs
```